# How to collapse all divs that don't have a form input value set in them

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have several DIV's each with a form in them with standard form elements (selects, text boxes, radios, checkboxes etc), is there a way to collapse all the divs that don't have a (non-default) value set on at least one of the inputs?

Comment: loop through those inputs, check it's value. If empty `''`, hide it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "collapse" ?

Comment: You'll need to test `node.value` against `node.getAttribute('value')` to check if it's the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through each form, and search for form elements, check the current `value` property against the `defaultValue`, which will hold the elements default value (what it was on pageload)

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var self = this;

    $('form', this).find(':input').each(function() {
        if (this.value != this.defaultValue) {
            $(self).hide();
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I like that approach!

Answer (score 1):

Depends what your defaults are, but you could loop and check:

```
$("div form").each(function() {
    $(this).find(......) //find your inputs
    //check

    //if not default
    $(this).closest("div").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to address the critical elements directly with a jquery selector, you might consider this piece of code as a beginning:

```
var $default_input_divs = $('div input[value="defaultvalue"]').parent('div');
$default_input_divs.remove();
```

JSfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/vaQYS/